# Dissolving features according to the ordering field in QGIS

Tags: qgis, overlapping-features, dissolve, polygon-creation, order

Using an attribute field, I want to dissolve overlapping features according to a specified order. For instance, if I have three overlapping features, like the image below, I'd want to keep the purple feature, then the red one and then what's left the remaining feature

[image: Three overlapping features with different attributes]

Dissolving would look like this.

[image: Result of the dissolve process with specified order]

I would need to do this with thousands of features so editing manually is not an option.

Comment: What you are looking for is "Difference", not "Dissolve"

Comment: What do you mean by dissolve? What I understand is that you would like to specify the order of features based on an attribute value. ??

Comment: Features are in the same layer, so I guess difference would not be an option. Also, i need to change the features and cant have overlaps. If 1 overlaps 2 and 3 for instance, then the new feature aggregates all three.

Comment: If you are ok with using postgis: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/379300/how-to-remove-overlaps-and-keep-highest-priority-polygon

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is actually a solution to this problem that does not require a script. It requires multiple processing steps, but you could chain these tools together in a graphical model.

I'm using QGIS, but I believe this could be done in ArcMap in a similar fashion (though perhaps using different tools).

Say you have three features in a single layer that overlap like so:

[image: overlapping rectangles]

**Step 1:** Reassign the primary key column (in my case ID) for the layer so it reflects the order in which you'd like the overlaps retained. So the feature with ID = 1 will be left completely intact, feature 2 will be prioritized over feature 3, feature 3 over feature 4, and so on.

**Step 2:** Run Union, setting the layer as the only input (leaving the Overlay layer empty). This will perform a Union between the layer and itself, resulting in (in my case) 12 features.

[image: Union screenshot]

Result:

[image: Union output]

**Step 3:** Run Delete Duplicate Geometries on the output from *Step 2*. This reduced the number of features to 7.

[image: Delete Duplicate Geometries screenshot]

**Step 4:** Run Join Attributes by Location, setting the Base Layer to the output from Step 3, the Join Layer to the original layer from *Step 1*, the Geometric predicate to "within", and the Join type to "Take attributes from the first matching feature only (one-to-one)". This is where the magic happens, since the first matching feature in each case is determined from the order of the primary key.

[image: Join attributes by location screenshot]

**Step 5:** Finally, run Dissolve, setting the Dissolve field to `"ID_2"`, which is the ID of the original features that were joined in *Step 4*.

Final result:

[image: final output]

Comment: Many thanks Mike, solves it wonderfully. Thank you!

Comment: I've tested but stumbled against another issues. In my case, the order is not a primary key (i.e. they are not unique, just a field where I set the order; several features have order 1, others order 2, etc.). Would there be a way to give the mininum value (highest rank) to the feature? Another way could be to give a primary key starting with the highest ranking to the lowest? Or avoid the primary key (which I'm not sure how to assign or reassing) altogether and just give the feature the minimum value when joining by location?

Comment: This method will only work if the order is also the primary key, which is also unique. Are you using QGIS? If your primary key is "id", you should be able to reassign it from swither field using field calculator, but you'll first need to make it unique. If you want to use another field for the order that is not unique, I think you'll have to write a script as I haven't found a way to do it.

Comment: Thnaks Mike. The field is not unique so I found a workaround which works despite the time it takes. I first separated the shapefile into several others based on the unique values of the field that gives the order of overlay. For each file I created an identifier field. I then made an union with the graphic model of all files. The resulting file has the same number of identifier fields as the number of files. I then created a new field where I had a CASE when then function. E.g.: when field4=1 then newfield=4, and so on according to the order I wanted. Perhaps I bit confusing, but it worked.

Answer (score 6):

You can use "Control feature rendering order" option under "Layer Rendering" in "Layer Style" panel.

[image]

Open `Define Order` window by clicking `AZ` button. Add field name (`Type` here) and values (1: purple, 2: red, 3: green).

[image]

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: Kadir that would suit me but it will only change how I view the features, not actually change them. In your example features still overlap.

Comment: Then, what do you mean by Dissolve? If you dissolve features, you lose the colors and three features become one feature.

Comment: Ok then lets put it this way. I have several overlapping features. They have a field which classifies them. I want to a have aggregated features (no overlaps) according to a hierarchy. If feature with code 1 overlaps codes 2 and 3, then the feature keeps code 1. If a feature with code 2 overlaps one with code 3, then the resulting feature will have code 2. And so on

Comment: I'm sorry. I couldn't understand what exactly you would like to do. :(

Comment: My instinct tells me you might need a script.

Comment: Thanks Kadir, lets if somebody can suggest something without scripts

Answer (score 1):

You can use Union - Aggregate - Dissolve.

I have a field called `prio` in my polygon layer, and where polygons overlap I want to keep the lowest prio value. So for example when a prio 1 and prio 2 overlaps, I want to erase the prio 2 polygon overlap:

[image]

Then Dissolve by prio field with the option `keep separate features disjoint` ticked.

[image]