# Cutting overlapping line by priorities

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, overlapping-features, path, line-on-line-overlay

[image]

I have several line layers following an unique and same path.

On some part, these layers overlap each others, so there are multiples segments overlapping.

I need to find a way which grants me the possibility of choosing which segment will "win" the overlapping competition (base on a priority system in the fields).

It's like having some trekking pathway being noted by people and on a segment you got "average" difficulty overlapped by "hard" difficulty and you want as final result "average" to be erased and replaced only on the part it conflicts with "hard" (except there is more than 2 categories).

Comment: Just to be sure, you have multiple layers? Not multiple overlapping features in the same layer? Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: Hello Bera, yes it is multiple layers, I add a screenshot in the topic where most of the layers are overlapping.

Comment: My first though was to find the 1st and last point of every features then cut the other layers with them based on priorities, but I only found the "cut line by point" on SAGA and it doesn't work.

Comment: have a look at this similar [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/379300/how-to-remove-overlaps-and-keep-highest-priority-polygon) (you would have to adapt it from polygon to lines, and from single to multiple layers -- or just put all your geometries in a single layer first)