# Finding and removing overlaps in a shapefile using PostgreSQL

Tags: postgis, shapefile, shape-area

I was wondering if it's possible to remove any overlapping areas that occurs in a column based on a sample of the table for the shapefile with 2 important columns:

1. Shape area
2. Geom

I'm trying to find the total shape areas without any overlaps.
I think it's best to minus the sum of the shape area with  `ST_Intersection` but the function needs with 2 different geom:
`geography ST_Intersection( geography geogA , geography geogB )` which I took from the PostGIS site. I feel like I'm really close to figuring it out ie. if the table is called "table", then something like this:

```
SELECT sum(A.shape_area) as "sum with overlaps",
       ST_Area(ST_Intersection(A.geom, B.geom)) AS "intersected area"
FROM   table A 
JOIN   table B ON ST_Contains(A.geom, B.geom)
GROUP BY a.geom, B.geom;
```

But as you can see, my results were off as the sum - intersected area should be bigger than 0. Can someone point out my mistake?

Basically, my goal is to count any area once (regardless of the overlaps)
[image]

Comment: You can remove the overlaps like this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/379300/removing-overlaps-and-keeping-highest-priority-polygon-using-postgis. What units are you coordinate system in, degrees/meters?

Comment: @BERA Thanks for the redirect! I'm using 4326 SRID to transform the data so latitude/longitude degrees, I believe.

Comment: Referring to a table as a "shapefile" is very confusing -- Once loaded into the database, it's no longer in shapefile format.  It's always important in self-joins to restrict the comparisons to prevent A/B and B/A pairs.  The usual way to do this is by integer ID column constriant `B.id > A.id`. I wouldn't trust the comparison operator for `GROUP BY` geometries to function correctly.

Comment: Note that, geometrically this is more complex than you may think: while my answer in @BERA's link does indeed give you non-overlapping polygons, it depends on a hierarchy (which btw. you could simply apply e.g. by using `id` instead of `prio`) and can only remove overlaps non-symmetrically, e.g. when two polygons overlap, only one of them gets reduced - creating an equal cut in both is highly complex (and expinentially so for cases where more than two overlap each other).

Comment: I also added a "randomness" to the prio. For example two polygons with prio 1 got the prios 1.123242345, 1.470274 so when these two overlapped someone always got erased.

Comment: @BERA good catch, for that case you had back then. With an incremental ID this is not necessary...but you could also e.g. use area as a deciding factor (for non-regular polygons, that is).