# Removing overlaps in QGIS

Tags: qgis, overlay

I want to remove overlaps in the picture below (showing trees). It doesn't matter which tree is cut, but I do want to keep all my attributes, because I need them later on.

It is also important that they don't get merged during the process, since I need with all the trees and unique values afterwards... I can't use the difference tool, because I have only have 1 layer (trees as input) and no overlay (because it doesn't matter which tree is being cut).

[image]

Comment: A layer is a manifestation of a data source with drawing rules. There are only two enabled layers visible in the canvas.  Do you want to remove *features*? Or maybe just symbolize the layer with transparency so you can see the image layer below?

Comment: Sorry, the satellite image or all the layers on the left are not important. I want to cut all overlapping parts of the polygon (urban trees). So that is of just one layer. I want to keep my values of every separate tree entity in my attribute table. I created this layer with a buffer of 8 meters around a tree pit (point). This created overlapping layers. Though, I want to delete the overlap between the buffer zones

Comment: Here is a PostGIS [solution](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/379300/removing-overlaps-and-keeping-highest-priority-polygon-using-postgis)

Comment: If you create the polygon yourself by buffering point you could as well try the QGIS model "Non-overlapping buffer from points" from the QGIS hub (https://plugins.qgis.org/models/8/) to directly create an output that suit you

Comment: Run the GRASS  v.clean tool in processing on your layer (break, snap, bpol), then run the delete duplicate geometries tool in Vector- General tool on the result.

Comment: Thank you these answers are really helpful and solve my problem!

Answer (score 2):

1. Union the layer with itself
2. Aggregate with group expression `geom_to_wkt( $geometry )`, aggregate function `first values` for all fields you want to keep
3. Dissolve by the fields you kept.

[image]